# Postgresql dblink extension is too slow

Tags: postgresql

I need to merge results from two tables on different databases in a view.
As far as I search, we can use dblink extension for this.

I decided to use dblink extension to merge these tables via union all but it became too slow.

For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test1;
```

After this, I run below queries in pgadmin and analyzed union all in same database

```
CREATE TABLE A_Test1(id int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO A_Test1
   SELECT x
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;   
CREATE TABLE B_Test1(id int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO B_Test1
   SELECT x
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;   
SELECT id FROM  A_Test1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM  B_Test1
-- a_test1 TotalCost 14425 , Actual Total Time 202.336
-- b_test1 TotalCost 14425 , Actual Total Time 216.108
-- Append  TotalCost 38850 , Actual Total Time 607.316
```

```
CREATE DATABASE Test2;
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;--Run on Test1 Database
CREATE TABLE B_Test2(id int NOT NULL);--Run on Test2 Database

INSERT INTO B_Test2 --Run on Test2 Database
   SELECT x
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;
```

And using dblink extension, results look like the below

```
SELECT id FROM A_Test1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM dblink('dbname=test2','select id from b_test2') AS f(id integer);
-- a_test1          TotalCost 14425 , Actual Total Time 197.493
-- Function Scan    TotalCost 10    , Actual Total Time 3188.188
-- Append           TotalCost 19440 , Actual Total Time 3537.514
```

Total time with dblink is longer than the one without dblink.

1. What is the workaround of this ? We solved this problem using same one database instead of two seperate databases.
2. What is the reason of this slowness?
3. Do Postgresql developers or developers developing this extension think to resolve this performance problem?
4. What is the meaning of totalcost?
5. Which metrics Must I use to interpret results ?"-- b_test1 TotalCost 14425" 's totalcost is lower than "-- Function Scan    TotalCost 10" 's. But it's totaltime is too lower than function scan's.

As we interpret totaltime, dblink is too slow. But as we interpret totalcost first one is lower than dblink?

Comment: I don't understand the flurry of questions at the end, but your basic problem seems so be that fetching a table via dblink is slower than using a local table. How can that surprise you?

Comment: DbLink is somewhat outdated. The modern (and probably faster) replacement is to use a foreign table: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html

Comment: My backgorund is Sql server.I try to adapt postgresql.Cross database union is fast in Sql Server.I thougt that Postgresql had a solution without performance issues like Sql server.

Comment: If you need "cross database joins" a lot, you should consider schemas, rather than databases (Postgres schemas are more flexible than SQL Server's) The concepts are very different between SQL Server and Postgres. Using DbLink (or foreign tables) in Postgres is more like using a linked servers in SQL Server.

Comment: Do you mean that you must use different schemas for every databases in one database ?

Comment: Yes. If you use databases in SQL Server to just "logically" divide tables, then use schemas in Postgres